# HQL Query based on date on a TimeStamp column?

Tags: java, sql, hql

I have a table with a `TimeStamp` column in it. I want to execute a query on that table giving condition that only checks for Date on that column not time.
How can I do that in HQL?

Say my column has value `07/23/2013 04:40:59 PM` and I want to select query to only check for `7/23/2013` and ignore the time.

Answer (score 3):

You can put two constraints into your HQL, one that specifies greater than or equal to the start of the date you are searching on, and one that specifies less than the next day.

i.e.

```
table.timestamp >= 07/23/2013 AND table.timestamp < 07/24/2013
```

or

```
from Table where to_char(TimeStamp,'YYYY/MM/DD') = '2013/07/23'
```

Comment: Because 1st solution is hardcoded. It's not very good to calculate next date (24 Jul) an then pass it into sql query. 2nd solution is better, so I clicked upvote now.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the `DAY(...)`, `MONTH(...)`, `YEAR(...)` [expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-expressions)

```
WHERE MONTH (timestampcol) = 7 
  AND DAY (timestampcol) = 23 
  AND YEAR (timestampcol) = 2013
```

In Postgres this is mapped to [extract(field from timestamp)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function

Answer (score 0):

Wilts C. from Table where `to_char(TimeStamp,'YYYY/MM/DD') = '2013/07/23'` is the correct answer. The other answers do not relate to HQL or do not address how to format a date input for comparison in HQL.

I don't have enough reputation to vote it up. HQL will take a date string input (beware of SQL injection) and compare it to your column date String format. Another example: `to_char(surveyDate,'YYYY/MM/DD') between '2000/09/23' and '2015/07/23'`

Answer (score 0):

**Java 8**

`.setParameter("dateParameter",  Date.valueOf(fullDate), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`

*Where:*

> Date is `java.sql.Date`, fullDate is  `java.time.LocalDate` and the
> field trying to compare is declared with `@Temporal`.

https://thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using oracle as DBMS, you can use **trunc(timestamp)** in your HQL to discard hour part of timestamp.

Try this tutorial: [Document](http://www.coding-dude.com/wp/java/hql-date-datetime-quick-tip/)

Answer (score -2):

In MySQL HQL can be something like:

```
where DATE_FORMAT(date_column,'MM/dd/yyyy') = :date
```

where date is '7/23/2013'